# keras understanding parameters for LSTM layer

Tags: keras, lstm

on the [page](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/sentiment-analysis-using-embeddings-f3dd99aeaade), why does lstm layer has 131584 parameters?
each sentence has 500 words max and word embedding have 128 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of parameters of LSTM, taking input vectors of size m
and giving output vectors of size n

is:

> 4(nm+n^2)

With bias vectors, the number becomes:

> 4(nm+n^2 + n)

131584 = 4*(128*128 + 128^2 + 128)

More: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/number-of-parameters-in-an-lstm-model